Difference between #FOO @BAR and :BAZ: in emacs org-mode?
What's the difference between these three?
#FOO
@BAR
:BAZ:

I know :BAZ: is a tag and you can view a tag list by selecting the tag. I also know that @BAR turns blue in my editor, but don't know anything more than that, and #FOO turns darker/gray then normal text.
When should you use each and what are their features?

When I do emacs -q and open an org buffer, #FOO and @BAR are just normal text as foo or bar.

#FOO and @BAR don't seem to do anything in my emacs org mode either. You might investigate by using C-u C-x = to find out what faces the blue and gray are. The face name might tell you what feature is being used there.

What each is depends on the context: fundamentally they are all just strings, but depending on the context where each is found, it may have some meaning to Org mode. As you say, :BAZ: is a tag, but only if it is found at the end of a headline (strictly speaking the tag is BAZ - the colons are just punctuation to separate one tag from another, and the whole thing has to be enclosed in colons). @BAR might be a citation key if it occurs in a citation context. #FOO is just a string always AFAIK - maybe you are thinking of # FOO with a space or #+FOO. The first one might be a ...

... comment if it occurs in the right context (every character from the beginning of the line to the # is white space), but it is just a string in any other context. The second one might be a keyword in the right context, but is just a string in any other context. So you have to show us the context where you place these things in order for us to figure out what they are.
